# Rust - right way to implement a shared context for multiple structs

Tags: struct, rust

I am currently implementing my first library in Rust, and as it is the case with many developers coming from other languages like Java etc. I am struggling to find right solutions for common patterns/use cases in Rust.

My Rust library has multiple structs. Many of them need to have access to some common configuration options which are essential for their function. For example:

```
pub struct A {
    pub context: Context
}

pub struct B {
    pub context: Context
}

pub struct Context {
    pub dbUri: String
}
```

The context will be passed to each struct once when the struct is initialized. The context attribute values might change at runtime which should make these changes available to any dependent struct. Structs should be able to make changes to context if required. It might be required to make the context available to different threads in the future.

The best solution I could find so far is to use Mutex wrapped in Arc as described [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

I would like to know whether this is the right way to implement my requirement, and what are other available options?

Comment: `Arc<Mutex<Context>>` seems to solve your problem, so it's not really clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: depending on your memory constraints, cloning the context (or just substructs of context that are required by component) could be enough (in case it is immutable, as it seems to be in your example)

Comment: You can also use `Rc<RefCell>` if you don't need access from multiple threads. Consider using the Mutex from [`parking_lot`](https://github.com/Amanieu/parking_lot) if you care about performance (or don't need the poisoning functionality).

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted to ask is how to *hide dependency from clients* in Rust. Unfortunately, every approach looks unwieldy in Rust.

1. `Rc<Refcell<T>>` and its friends. It's really tedious to repeat the types. And `Rc` is infectious. One `Rc` and every other usage site becomes `Rc`.
2. References and a bunch of lifetimes. In Rust, lifetime is also infectious. Every client must tag the lifetime on themselves if they want to hold the service as field.
3. Give up holding dependencies in fields. Pass context in parameters. This is implementation leak into client code. In this way, the client code becomes more coupled to the implementation of the service code. Moreover, your code will essentially become procedural code.

It's your choice, anyway. Procedural Programming isn't that fearsome after all.

Comment: `Rc` is not infectious (though `RefCell` is in some way).